# How to limit Team Drive search to a single team drive?

Tags: google-drive, search, google-workspace-for-business, google-shared-drive

I'm trying to search for files with a particular term in a single specific team drive.   But when I search, I get hundreds of results across 15 different team drives, most of which aren't the one I am looking for.

I tried adding "owner:" to the search, but then nothing was found.   This isn't right, because in the first few pages of results I see that there *are* files that match in the team drive I specified.

So how can I limit my search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short Answer

Use the advanced search and select Location > Team Drives > Specific Team Drive

## Detailed instructions

1. Go to https://drive.google.com using your G Suite account
2. Click on the dropdown button at the right of the Google Drive's search box.
3. Click on the button next to Location, click on Team Drives, then on the name of the team drive that you want to search on.
4. Type the search terms and click on the search button or press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

## Reference

[Find files in Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375114?hl=en)